# Whats different about laravel redirect()->route() and to_route()

Tags: php, laravel

i have a question here, i'am try to reading laravel routing documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes) and i confuse about whats different about this redirect()->route() and  and to_route()
Thanks

```php
// Generating URLs...
$url = route('profile');
 
// Generating Redirects...
return redirect()->route('profile');
 
return to_route('profile');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not different, [to_route](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-to-route) is just shorter. You can see in the source code of laravel ([Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/0b3fae2e8dd094433a760b09eb4366bb139fcf88/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L878-L892)):

```
    /**
     * Create a new redirect response to a named route.
     *
     * @param  string  $route
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  int  $status
     * @param  array  $headers
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    function to_route($route, $parameters = [], $status = 302, $headers = [])
    {
        return redirect()->route($route, $parameters, $status, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Remember to add references (links) to what you are sharing, so it is easier (see that I have added links to your answer)